# What is new $class() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project in CodeIgnitor that is written by someone else
While studying the code I came across the following line:

```
$CI = new $class();
```

is this $class a PHP built in function to instantiate a generic object? or what is it exactly
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class, `class ExampleClass`, and you have a variable somewhere and you call it `$class = "ExampleClass";` you can write the code you specified in the question, which is the same as write `$CI = new ExampleClass()`. In php you can do that even with variables.